# Как скрыть класс по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, button

Подскажите, как скрыть класс и саму кнопку по ее нажатию?

Comment: Подробнее напишите, что Вам нужно

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрываем класс все элементы с классом `className`.

```
var elements =  document.getElementsByClassName("className");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Скрываем кнопку по Id

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Одно из двух: или `.display = "none";`, или `.visibility = "hidden";`

Comment: @Igor `.visibility = "hidden"` как я знаю просто прячет элемент но визуальное место не освобождает. Но если автору вопроса это подойдёт то почему бы и нет.

Comment: Я, видимо, неясно выразился. "hidden" не является одним из допустимых значений свойства `style.display`.

Comment: @Igor  А, понял, перепутал. Спасибо, исправляю.